# Stored Procedure with SELECT and NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchProfile]

(
@Type varchar,
@Name varchar
)

AS
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Profiles 
WHERE ((@Type IS NULL) 
 OR (dbo.Profiles.Type = @Type)) 
 AND  ((@Name IS NULL) 
 OR (Name = @Name));
```

When I execute this with:

```
exec SearchProfile NULL, NULL
```

It returns all rows which is OK, but when I change one of NULLs to some value...

```
exec SearchProfile 'abc', NULL
```

It doesn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify lengths on those varchar parameters - I suspect as this is omitted the parameters are only 1 character in size.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the length of the variables.

If you run

```
DECLARE @Type varchar = 'abc'

SELECT @Type
```

It returns

```
a
```

So change it to something like

```
@Type varchar(50),
@Name varchar(50)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36351)